# android, how to play a line of videofiles?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-activity, playlist

I have an android application and it allows to play a videofile, in particular an episode of different series from one web media resource .

A videofile is being played next way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mp4url), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

where `mp4url` - is a String variable

Now I want to allow the programm play a queue of videofiles.

I tryed to make next way:

```
for(int iteration=arg2;iteration<episodes.size(); iteration++){
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent1.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mp4Url1), "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

where `arg2` shows a position of chosen videofile and `episodes` is a ArrayList variable for the queue of videofile to be played after chosen videofile.

But it did not work. Actually all videofiles are playeable but
simultaneously. I need them to play in turn. How can I reorganise my code effectivly?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: u need to listen to event when ur video is ended and then u can start playing next one

Comment: I undrestand. Is there a possibility to see this on an example?

Comment: ur using MediaPlayer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an arraylist of movie urls(e.g `yourURLList`)
Define an `int` constant as `static final int VIDEO_PLAYBACK_FINISHED = 32`

You can keep a count to keep track of which video is being played like:

```
static int VIDEO_RUNNING = 0
```

Create a method like this inside the caller activity:

```
private void startMovie(int serialOfMovie){
        String vdoURL= yourURLList.get(serialOfMovie);//array list of movie urls
        if(vdoURL != null)
        {
            //video url for that index is found,if not then it would not enter here
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(vdoURL), "video/mp4");
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                     VIDEO_PLAYBACK_FINISHED);
        }

}
```

And inside the caller activity(the one from which you are invoking the intents you are creating) don't forget to add this snippet:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == VIDEO_PLAYBACK_FINISHED) {

             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 //one video is finished
                 VIDEO_RUNNING++; //increase which vdo is running count
                 startMovie(VIDEO_RUNNING);
             }
         }
     }
```

Now when you are about to play this series of movies(starting from the beginning),just call `startMovie(VIDEO_RUNNING);//VIDEO_RUNNING is 0 initially,so it will point the first url in url list.`

**Remember** if you are using *MediaPlayer* to play movie in the activity(the one you call using intents with movie url),then when the movie has finished playing you should `finish` that activity. Like if you have a *MediaPlayer* instance called `mPlayer` in that activity then you should do this:

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new
    OnCompletionListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        finish();              
    }
});
```

This way you should have the queue effect with movies being played one after another.

Comment: Unfortunately all videofiles end with result 0 (RESULT_CANCELLED), even if they finished by themselves (an episode is ended).

Comment: If I change resultCode checking from RESULT_OK to RESULT_CANCELL next episode will be played to.